# Align points in centre of bars (DC.JS composite chart)

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have a dc.js composite chart that has an ordinal bar chart one and a line chart. The bar chart values are on the left y-axis and the line chart values are on the right y-axis.

Is it possible to align the data points for the line in the centre of the bars (directly above the tick-marks)?

[image]

```
var oneWayComposite = dc.compositeChart('#chart');


var oneWayBar = dc.barChart(oneWayComposite)
        .dimension(featureDim)
        .barPadding(1)
        .group(grp)
        // .centerBar(true)
        .valueAccessor(function(p) {return p.value.count; });


var oneWayLine = dc.lineChart(oneWayComposite)
        .dimension(featureDim)
        .group(grp)
        .colors('#000000')
        .renderArea(false)
        // .interpolate('basis')
        .useRightYAxis(true)
        .valueAccessor(function(p) {return p.value.density; });

oneWayComposite.width(width)
    .margins(mrgn)
    .height(height)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .yAxisLabel("Count of Cases")
    .rightYAxisLabel("Target Density")
    .group(grp)
    .compose([oneWayBar,oneWayLine]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/662

Seems like a workaround is to assign `._rangeBandPadding(1)` the composite chart. Though as mentioned in the github thread that breaks the bar sizes, so adding `.gap(1)` and `.centerBar(true)` to the bar chart got everything looking nice.