# DC.js Composite chart Align points of Line chart in center of bars

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to create a composite chart and my requirements are to draw a bar chart, a line chart and a dotted line chart. For that I draw a composite chart. Now I am having problem that points of line chart starts from start of bar chart, but I need that to start from center of line.

You can see the problem in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nauman3128/nr0rgzvc/8/).

[image: Composite Chart with line chart points on start of bar]

I got some help from Stackoverflow that is:

[Align points in centre of bars (DC.JS composite chart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426356/align-points-in-centre-of-bars-dc-js-composite-chart)

> Seems like a workaround is to assign ._rangeBandPadding(1) the composite chart. Though as mentioned in the github thread that breaks the bar sizes, so adding .gap(1) and .centerBar(true) to the bar chart got everything looking nice.

but after that I got this output

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/nauman3128/nr0rgzvc/9/][2]
```

[image: After implementing found solution]

Answer (score 5):

I can't explain why this works, but with some odd combination of range bands and old-style `.gap(1)`, I was able to get it to draw properly.

The trick is

```
        ._rangeBandPadding(1)
```

on the composite chart, and

```
        .gap(1)
        .centerBar(true)
```

on the child bar chart, pretty much as stated in the original question. So this is essentially a duplicate of the earlier question and answer, but I've applied it to your JSFiddle in this fork:

http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/nr0rgzvc/22/

Also, it's important *not* to set `barPadding` for the child bar chart. So we are using range-band layout for the composite, and classic gap-padding for the bar chart, which sounds like a very bad idea... but the output looks okay!